# How can i pass an array of characters to my function

Tags: c

I want to pass a char array which contains many strings:

I have `char test[4]` which has to contain 4 strings

`"abc" , "asd", "erwe", "wert"`

How can I store these string in a `test[4]` of type character.

I learnt that we can use `char *s="qwerrt";` to represent a string. But if I want to create a array of string How can I do that?

Comment: The same way you would create an array of any other type. If `int s[10]` is an array of 10 ints, and `char *` is used to address a string, then `char *s[10]` can be used to store an array of 10 strings.

Answer (score 1):

either declare a 2d array:

```
 char array[4][100]; // row( number of strings ), column ( max size of the biggest string )
```

or :

```
 char *array[4]; // array of strings that can hold 4 strings
```